# UITabBar not changing tint color Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

This is very odd. My global tint is set and my icons colors are set to the default purple I have. Yet at run time its blue. Any tips? Ive checked around and have not seen anyone else with this problem.

Storyboard:

[image: StoryBoard]

Run Time:

[image: Run Time]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, when you want to change the tint color of `UITabBar` programmatically, `UITabBar` class gives you several tint color properties:

- `tintColor`: `TabBarItem`'s color.
- `barTintColor` : `TabBar`'s background bar's color.
- `unselectedItemTintColor` : color of unselected items.

so if you change the `tintColor`, barItems' color would be changed.

### ...but, Why it doesn't works on IB?

When you set a specific color to UITabBar's item in IB, there's an option named `Image Tint`.

[image: imageTint]

Changing a `Tint` option on "View" section won't affect anything to TabBar's items but only `Image Tint` option can change tabBar's item color.

storyboard's global tint color option changes `Tint` option of "View" section, but doesn't affect default value of `Image Tint` option, so It doesn't affect the tab bar's tint color.

### So.. Why `Image Tint` option doesn't affected?

I can't explain why doesn't it affected. Maybe Apple had an issue with this, or kind of bug.

there are some workarounds for setting an image color :

- Explicitly Set an `Image Tint` option to UITabBarController's TabBar object.

You may should set every `TabBarController`'s `Image Tint` option, because it doesn't affects global setting.

- Programmatically change global UITabBar's tintColor.

At `AppDelegate.swift`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, paste following code

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = <#Color what you want#>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem, which was fixed by changing the "Render As" property to "Default" instead of "Original". You can find this in your Asset Library, when selecting your images on right right hand side under "Render As" in the attributes inspector.